# How to create object by identical values from 2 objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an object by comparing 2 objects and if there are identical id's - then to create an object.

for example :

```
obj1 = [{"id":1,"name":"john"},{"id":2,"name":"kile"},{"id":3,"name":"kenny"},
{"id":4,"name":"stan"}]

obj2 = [{"id":1,"name":"dan"},{"id":1,"name":"ben"},{"id":1,"name":"sarah"},
{"id":2,"name":"kelly"}]
```

The result i'm looking for is :

```
result = [{1:{"id":1,"name":"john"},{"id":1,"name":"dan"},
    {"id":1,"name":"ben"},{"id":1,"name":"sarah"},

 //both objects from obj1 & obj 2 which holds the same ID are now in new 
  object "1" - which is the id that's common to them//

{2:{{"id":2,"name":"kile"},
{"id":2,"name":"kelly"}}}]
```

To be more explicit:

1. Find in both objects matching id's
2. Stack them both in one object... so the new object will contains matching id's objects from them both....

I've tried :

```
var obj_names_1 = [{"id":1,"name":"john"},{"id":2,"name":"kile"},
{"id":3,"name":"kenny"},
{"id":4,"name":"stan"}];

var obj_names_2 = [{"id":1,"name":"dan"},{"id":1,"name":"ben"},
{"id":1,"name":"sarah"},
{"id":2,"name":"kelly"}];

 function getMessages(obj1, obj2){
    var messages_tab = [];
    $.each(obj1, function(){

        var messages_wrap = this;
        var recieved_messages_id = this.id;
        $.each(obj2, function(){
            var sent_messages_id = this.id;
            if(recieved_messages_id == sent_messages_id){


                messages_tab.push({1:[this,messages_wrap]}); // key 0 should 
                be the common id

            }

        });
    });
    return messages_tab;
}

console.log(getMessages(obj_names_1,obj_names_2));
```

But here the first problem is that it's not pushing more than 1 result

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/hpwn73Ln/1/)

Comment: I think result isn't valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `array#concat` both your arrays and then use `array#reduce` to push objects in array having same `id`.

NOTE: The value corresponding to `id` should be array.

```js
var obj1 = [{"id":1,"name":"john"},{"id":2,"name":"kile"},{"id":3,"name":"kenny"},{"id":4,"name":"stan"}],
    obj2 = [{"id":1,"name":"dan"},{"id":1,"name":"ben"},{"id":1,"name":"sarah"},{"id":2,"name":"kelly"}]
    result = obj1.concat(obj2).reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.id] = r[o.id] || [];
      r[o.id].push(o);
      return r;
    },{});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks - i'm not so good with es6/5 functions.... but i'll start learning from now on!